# Automatically created files don't have right permissions

Tags: server, permissions

I'm a beginner who's in charge of managing a remote hosted server (a vps so).

I've been encountering a problem for several weeks that I can't solve: When I upload a .jar file via ftp, and then execute the file, it generates new folders / files. That is normal, but the problem is that those files don't have the permissions I would like they have.

Those files have the permission rw-r--r--, but I don't know which user has those files.

I know I can change the permissions of the files, but it's not practical to do it every time...

I tried to change the umask to 000, I know it's not "good" for security, but anyway it doesn't seem to affect the automatically generated files.

Would you know how to change the default permissions of these files ? Or how to attach them to a particular user?

Comment: "*When I upload a file via ftp, then it runs (normally), and generates new folders / files*" - It's really not clear what you are describing here. And I think it's best that we know exactly what you're doing since it seems you think this is where the problem starts. Can you edit your question and be more specific?

Comment: @Nmath thx for your answer. I edited it, i hope it's more understandable now